# Documentation for 9yr old Spanish national traveling to UK

Tags: schengen, uk, passports, paperwork

We are a Spanish couple planing a trip to London with our 9 yr old son next month. I assume there is a minimum age for which you need to have your own documents, but I am not sure what that might be, and can't seem to find it online.

I know you can travel using your national ID card, but in Spain you are not required to have one until you are 14 yr old.

Comment: As far as. I can think, everyone who is traveling within the Schengen area needs some form of identification document, otherwise how can anyone verify whether they are a Schengen citizen or now?

Comment: @AdityaSomani It's not a travel within the Schengen area anyway.

Comment: Is the child mentioned in your passport?

Comment: @Relaxed: We have no passports, and won't pay 20€ each when carrying an ID card is enough :-)

Comment: @Relaxed well I meant the EEA...same question still applies...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Children do need some documentation in any case. In the past, children could also be included in their parents' passports but I think this is being phased out.

In fact, the requirements are often even more stringent for a child than for an adult because if the child does not appear to be yours (distinct surname), [merely having a passport or ID card might not be enough](https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/before-you-leave-for-the-uk). Similarly, in some countries, children leaving with only one of their parents might need an authorization from the other one.

Comment: I feel a bit embarashed because I thought I had scanned the whole UK site, but somehow the reference to children slipped me. No problem with filiation, spanish Id cards carry both parents names and surnames match.